# Test a value in a hash

Tags: ruby

Given the following code:

```
params = {:async => true, :contact_id => "101"}
puts "async is #{params['async']}"

if params['async'] == true
  puts "Do async stuff"
  # TODO Launch background task
  return [204, {}, ['']]
end
```

why do I never get the line `"Do async stuff"` when I do see the output `"async is true"`?

Comment: Yeah, the class is String.  Thank you!

Comment: I answered as per your post. if there is `"true"`, then write as `params[:async] == 'true'` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write as `params[:async]`. Your key `:async` is **`Symbol`**, not a **`String`**.

Here is the code after modification :

```
if params[:async] == true
  puts "Do async stuff"
  # TODO Launch background task
  return [204, {}, ['']]
end
```

Comment: "But why in Ruby on Rails can I use params[:id] and params['id'] interchangeably?"
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html

Comment: `Internally symbols are mapped to strings when used as keys in the entire writing interface`,you can see this from your link.

Answer (score 3):

There is no key `'async'` in your `params` hash, therefore it will return `nil` which is not equal to `true`. There *is* a key `:async` in your hash, but you are not asking for that key.

Comment: Thanks, I should also mention it on my answer. But you did.. +1